# cassandra - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input String

Tags: cassandra, date-format

I have another problem with cassandra.. I have export a table in Mysql in .csv format and import it in Cassandra.the Mysql table contains filds date and time of types Date and Time. I define these fields as varchar in cassandra. so when I import the .csv file and execute the below query, it shows me an error:
my query:

```
ResultSet rs = stmnt.ExecuteQuery("Select * from station info where IDstation = 1011 and IDinfo = 18412:);
while (rs.next) {
   System.out.println(rs1.getFloate(1) + "  " + 
                      rs1.getString(2) + "  " + 
                      rs1.getFloate(3) + " " + 
                      rs1.getString(4) + "  " + 
                      rs1.getInt(5) + "  " + 
                      rs1.getInt(6) + "  " + 
                      rs1.getString(7) + "  " + 
                      rs1.getFloate(8));
}
```

the 7th field in print command is date..

and the error is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input String: "6/2/1962"
    at org.apache.cassandracql.jdbc.cassandraResultSet.getInt(CassandraResultSet.java:619)
    at org.apache.cassandracql.jdbc.cassandraResultSet.getInt(CassandraResultSet.java:590)
```

I can not understand what it says... can anyone help me please?

Comment: To Anse: Just one suggestion apart from this article.  I found you asked questions but never accept answers (even for a good one).  People on this site spent their time to help you, when their answers solve your problem, it would be better if you can mark the best of them as acceptable in return :)

Answer (score 1):

Read what the stacktrace is telling you carefully

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input **String**: "6/2/1962"
>       at org.apache.cassandracql.jdbc.cassandraResultSet.**getInt**(CassandraResultSet.java:619)
>       at org.apache.cassandracql.jdbc.cassandraResultSet.**getInt**(CassandraResultSet.java:590)

The error you are getting is to do with an attempt to retrieve a string as a integer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the date column is coming at 7th position only and not anywhere else. I suggest you to improve your query by specifying the column names. For eg.,

`SELECT Col1, Col2... FROM Table`

This avoids confusion of column order.